# Django admin combine two tables into one page

Tags: django-admin

I have several models that I would like to be display in a single admin page. Here are my models:

```
class Server(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=44, choices=TYPES)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    environment = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=ENVIRONMENTS)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=LOCATONS)
    cpu = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    ram = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    os = models.CharField(max_length=24, choices=OSs, default='CentOS 6.3')
    eth0_ip = models.IPAddressField(unique=True)
    eth0_mac = models.CharField(max_length=17, unique=True, null=True,
                           blank=True)
    confluence_page = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s%s.%s" % (self.type, self.number, self.environment)

class Real(Server):
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=MANUFACTURERS_REAL)
    rack = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=True, blank=True)
    rack_u = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    serial_num = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True, null=True,
                              blank=True)

class Virtual(Server):
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=20,
                                choices=MANUFACTURERS_VIRTUAL)
    host_id = models.ForeignKey(Real)
```

What I'm wondering is if there is anyway for me to create/extend/whatever an admin interface that would allow to view all objects from both databases. For example I can go into admin then when I click on the app name I get the change_list for both databases, and when I select a particular object, say a Virtual, I will get the admin interface to create or change a virtual object.

If I'm not clear, please let me know and I will do what I can to explain differently and more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Django admin inlines would help you IF there was a common foreign key to the parent model type you want to display:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin

In your instance, since Real is a child of Server, you could build an admin page for Real with inlines to see all the Virtual objects of that server in the admin.